# Imported VDB Fire Simulation Isn't Rendering on Transparent Background

Tags: rendering, transparency, volumetrics

I have this render of a fire simulation I made in Embergen. When I would render out the animation on a transparent background, everything would be fine until when it would save the final frame to my computer.
While rendering each frame I can see the VDB being rendered like normal, but when it finishes that frame, there's nothing on the final end result PNG....

This is what I see in the completed Render frame:
[image]

This is the thumbnail I see on my computer:
[image]

(you can see SOMETHING in the frame^)

But this is what I see when previewing the frame (OR opening it in After effects):
[image]

Help?

Also: When NOT rendering with a transparent background, there's no problem, and I can see each animation frame like normal.

Comment: Try openEXR instead of PNG or render with a black background

Comment: You can't render emission shaders over a transparent background, when I submitted this as a bug they explained why, but it was a long time ago and I forgot, it did make sense though.
However, check the compositor, it might be the culprit.

Comment: @FrederikSteinmetz It has no emission set though. It's all black body and temperature based... And no luck on the compositor.. Nothing special set there...

Comment: @Emir Sorry, still a blank render :/

Comment: Black Body is just a color, not a shader. It needs to go into the color of a shader to be rendered. In your case probably a volume shader.